# Digital Ocean: Sorry, we couldn't find an app in your repo

Tags: digital-ocean

I am trying to launch a static site (html,css and js). I have done this many times on digital ocean. First time I am getting this error and I have no idea how to solve it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Give the path to where your DockerFile is located